# Nginx / FastCGI crashing on me all the time

Tags: mono, nginx, fastcgi

Are there any Nginx / FastCGI gurus out there who can help me?

I'm running nginx 1.0.11 on Debian Squeeze serving Mono FastCGI (fastcgi-mono-server4 2.10.2.0). I am noticing that the FastCGI instances frequently crash in response to POST requests in excess of ~350,000 bytes. Though some requests of this magnitude are successful, they are more likely to fail with increased traffic. Additionally, oftentimes when a FastCGI instance fails, an Nginx worker process will be zombified (i.e. Nginx still handles requests but times out - no 502s are returned although all gateways may be down). I turned Nginx debugging on and noticed the following before a worker process and FastCGI instance crashed.

```
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 writev: 8
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 sendfile: @360448 32768
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 sendfile: 32768, @360448 32768:32768
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 writev: 8
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 sendfile: @393216 12167
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 sendfile: 12167, @393216 12167:12167
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 writev: 9
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 event timer del: 16: 1326314382071
2012/01/11 20:38:42 [debug] 1744#0: *141 event timer add: 16: 60000:1326314382072
```

These are just the last 10 items logged, but, if you'd like to see more, I can certainly post or PM. And lastly, here is my Nginx config file.

```
user                 www-data;
worker_processes     2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
events {
    worker_connections  2048;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {
    error_log               /var/log/error.log;
    include                 mime.types;
    default_type            application/octet-stream;           
    sendfile                on;
    keepalive_timeout       65;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary         on;
    gzip_comp_level   6;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js font/opentype application/font-woff;
    gzip_buffers      16 8k;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  my_server;
        root         /var/www;
        access_log   /var/log/host.access.log;

        location / {
            fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include                  fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass             backend;
            fastcgi_next_upstream    http_500 http_404 error timeout;
            fastcgi_read_timeout     60;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
            root /var/www;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error log reports that my worker processes have exited on signal 9. Is anyone familiar with signal 9? What might this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Mono's LOH and the lack of it's defragmenting was the issue. So this solution here was to throw more memory at the problem.

http://blog.mohammadjalloul.com/blogs/mo/archive/2010/02/21/the-large-object-heap.aspx